# Inkscape - removing a section of a filled path

Tags: inkscape

I'm new to Inkscape and have probably a simple question, BUT -- let's say I have an oddly shaped path that's filled with a color; I now want to remove a section (also oddly shaped) from inside that filled area. How do I go about that? I tried making a new path and filling that with yellow (the background color), but when I go to print it, it prints the full filled path, and then tries to print over it in yellow (I am printing 1 color at a time on an EggBot... all sorts of new adventure for me here). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The issue is you're filling the area with color rather than deleting/clearing the selected area. You essentially want the  inside selection to be transparent, otherwise it will print on top.

Comment: A screenshot would help to explain...

Answer (score 2):

- Mark the outer path.
- Hold shift.
- Mark the inner path.
- Select Path, difference.